# Creating csv file in bolts

Tags: apache-storm

I want to write Bolt Output to a csv file. Consider if i am reading data from spout and passing it to bolt,bolt doing some calculations and then writting that data to a csv file,Although i am having 2 spouts and 4 bolts instances running.

> In csv file i am writing Columns once and under that multiple data as
>   below

```
Example: Columns:  Empid,EmpSal,Address
           1,1000,Add1
           2,1500,Add2
           3,200,Add3
```

> but due to multiple intsance of bolts columns name are repeating in
>   csv file as follows :

```
Empid,EmpSal,Address
            1,1000,Add1
            Empid,EmpSal,Address
            2,1500,Add2
            ....
```

> so any one knows why columns are repeating

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

While I don't really understand your question but it is better to have a Bolt that acts as an accumulator. After you done with crunching data and your CSV file is ready to file; you send the data to a Bolt that acts as a writer and only this Bolt is write to the CSV file.  And even if you have a multiple instances of that Bolt, with the right synchronization, it is easy to ensure the correctness of the file.

I use Storm with Clojure, so the concurrent part is really easy and simple!